# COM-Object for Teams Client - Microsoft.Office.Uc

Tags: com, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

I am trying to access Microsoft Teams client **COM object**.

As it was possible with Skype For Business with Lync client object in PowerShell.

Exactly opposite to [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-client-docs/blob/master/docs/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office.md).

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\temp\Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\temp\microsoft.office.uc.dll")
$lyncclient = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()
$lyncclient2 = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.ContactInformationType]::Availability
$lyncclient.Self.Contact.GetContactInformation($lyncclient2);
```

This code results in presence of current Lync/Skype user.

```
$teamsClient = [Microsoft.Office.Uc.IUCOfficeIntegration]
$teamsClient.GetInterfaces()
```

Following small article https://www.msxfaq.de/teams/api/teams_presence.htm
I am not even able to recieve Com obj list in Get-ChildItem HKLM
only in Get-ChildItem HKCU.

My goal is to use the same functionality as Outlook does, to read presence of users in MS Teams.

Answer (score 5):

Teams is still exposing a few functionalities via COM. Its implementing the IUCOfficeIntegration interface, so Microsoft Outlook can show the Teams availibility status of a contact in Outlook itself.

More Infos on how the Office Integration works can be found here.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-client-docs/blob/master/docs/shared/integrating-im-applications-with-office.md

I just describe quickly what i have done to receive availibility informations via COM.
Notice that this is C# code. I hope that it still helps.

**Getting the ClassID of the Teams COM Class**.

When Outlook and Teams is installed, Teams will register itself as an IM Application capable of providing availibility informations to Outlook. This is done by writing a few registry nodes. The ClassID can be found here
**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\IM Providers\Teams**

**Getting Availibilities:**

To do so i basically reversed all of the steps of the linked article showing how to implement a client for Office Integration, because i want to consume the Teams client.
Notice that the Lync SDK needs to be installed (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824) because all of the Office Integration Interfaces are defined in it. (Reference to Microsoft.Office.Uc.dll needed). Maybe this library can be

```
class Program
{

  static void Main()
  {
    var version = "15.0.0.0";
    var teams = (IUCOfficeIntegration) new TeamsOfficeIntegration();

    var client = (IClient) teams.GetInterface(version, OIInterface.oiInterfaceILyncClient);

    var contactManager = client.ContactManager;

    var uri = "name@company.com";
    var contact = contactManager.GetContactByUri(uri);
    var availibility =
        (ContactAvailability) contact.GetContactInformation(ContactInformationType.ucPresenceAvailability);
  }

  [ComImport, Guid("00425F68-FFC1-445F-8EDF-EF78B84BA1C7")]
  public class TeamsOfficeIntegration
  {
  }
}
```

I will try to upload a small project to GitHub to demonstrate....

As Powershell is based on .NET this should somehow be possible as well. Or a small C# Interop library could be written.

Comment: Hi, I have the problem that I cannot find IM Providers in the registry. Therefore my application does not run properly... I have MS Teams and Outlook installed on my computer. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I just checked and IM Providers are located in HKEY_CURRENT_User and not in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Is this causing problems?

Comment: So the office integration document linked aboves says. It should be located in this node. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\IM Providers\. However i dont expect, that the Teams Guid is changing. So it should just work with the given one.

Comment: Hmm, I am always informed that the COM object is not registered when I run the debugger over the location "(IUCOfficeIntegration)new TeamsOfficeIntegration();"

Answer (score 0):

Teams does not use COM at all and never will.

We plan to support presence APIs in Microsoft Graph bit do not have a date to share.

Comment: Somehow then outlook 2013 is able to receive presence directly from the teams client. Which should use IM api as lync client

Comment: There are APIs to retrieve presence of a user from Microsoft Graph.  It might just be that Outlook is retrieving this info through the Microsoft Graph API.